# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' Flutter

Tags: flutter

I need help on the following error  type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
I tried every possible solution but I still cannot be able to solve it.

```
Future<List<Autogenerated>?> signInData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? token = prefs.getString('token');

    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post('$_baseUrl/api/gateway',
          data: {
            "ClientPackageId": "0cdd231a-d7ad-4a68-a934-d373affb5100",
            "PlatformId": "ios",
            "ClientUserId": "AhmedOmar",
            "VinNumber": VINumber
          },
          options: Options(
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
              "Charset": 'utf-8',
              "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
            },
          ));
      print("data is here");
      print(json.encode(response.data));
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("decoded");

        // return List<Autogenerated>.from(
        //     response.data.map((i) => Autogenerated.fromJson(i)));
        //return Autogenerated.fromJson(jsonDecode(json.encode(response.data)));
        return (response.data as List)
            .map((e) => Autogenerated.fromJson(e))
            .toList();
      } else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
        // call your refresh token api here and save it in shared preference
        print(response.statusCode);
        await getToken();
        signInData();
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load data');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I am getting error in the following line:

```
 return (response.data as List)
            .map((e) => Autogenerated.fromJson(e))
            .toList();
```

My model class below

```
class Autogenerated {
  int? id;
  int? sourceId;
  int? serviceId;
  int? categoryId;
  String? category;
  String? description;
  int? serviceResponsePropertyId;
  int? mappingId;
  bool? isVisible;
  int? packageRequestId;
  int? sortOrder;
  Value? value;

  Autogenerated(
      {this.id,
      this.sourceId,
      this.serviceId,
      this.categoryId,
      this.category,
      this.description,
      this.serviceResponsePropertyId,
      this.mappingId,
      this.isVisible,
      this.packageRequestId,
      this.sortOrder,
      this.value});

  Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['Id'];
    sourceId = json['SourceId'];
    serviceId = json['ServiceId'];
    categoryId = json['CategoryId'];
    category = json['Category'];
    description = json['Description'];
    serviceResponsePropertyId = json['ServiceResponsePropertyId'];
    mappingId = json['MappingId'];
    isVisible = json['IsVisible'];
    packageRequestId = json['PackageRequestId'];
    sortOrder = json['SortOrder'];
    value = json['Value'] != null ? new Value.fromJson(json['Value']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Id'] = this.id;
    data['SourceId'] = this.sourceId;
    data['ServiceId'] = this.serviceId;
    data['CategoryId'] = this.categoryId;
    data['Category'] = this.category;
    data['Description'] = this.description;
    data['ServiceResponsePropertyId'] = this.serviceResponsePropertyId;
    data['MappingId'] = this.mappingId;
    data['IsVisible'] = this.isVisible;
    data['PackageRequestId'] = this.packageRequestId;
    data['SortOrder'] = this.sortOrder;
    if (this.value != null) {
      data['Value'] = this.value!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Value {
  String? make;
  String? type;
  String? model;
  int? year;
  String? body;
  String? driveType;
  String? fueType;

  Value(
      {this.make,
      this.type,
      this.model,
      this.year,
      this.body,
      this.driveType,
      this.fueType});

  Value.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    make = json['make'];
    type = json['type'];
    model = json['model'];
    year = json['year'];
    body = json['body'];
    driveType = json['drive_type'];
    fueType = json['fue_type'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['make'] = this.make;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['model'] = this.model;
    data['year'] = this.year;
    data['body'] = this.body;
    data['drive_type'] = this.driveType;
    data['fue_type'] = this.fueType;
    return data;
  }
}
```

My response from API(It's long, I just shorten it)

```
[
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 11,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "AdjustedValues",
        "Value": [],
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 474,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13853506,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 11,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "ServiceStatus",
        "Value": {
            "StatusCode": 1,
            "StatusDescription": "Ok",
            "StatusDetail": "",
            "RestServiceStatus": null,
            "ServiceResource": null
        },
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 475,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13853506,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "CarId",
        "Value": 120354,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 100,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13853506,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Year",
        "Value": 2017,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 103,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13853506,
        "SortOrder": 6
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Full Model Description",
        "Value": "2017 AUDI A3 Sedan 1.0T FSI S tronic [2016-2017]",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 104,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13853506,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
```

I cannot display data in lisview and I think it is because of this error. Please can you check there and please assist. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `e` seems to be of type `List<dynamic>`. But the method `fromJson(e)` expects a `Map<String, dynamic>`. Check what `e` really is and if it is suitable to use it (without converting it) as a parameter for `fromJson()`. Check the response's data structure.

Comment: e is type List<dynamic>, how can I convert it to be Map<String, dynamic>??

Comment: Everything depends on the data structure of `response.data`. What's the data structure of `response.data`?

Comment: @Dabbel, I just put it on my question.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably has been mis-attributed to the method `Autogenerated.fromJson`.

**Problem**

The method `Value.fromJson()` expects a `Map<String, dynamic>`:

`Value.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)`.

But the `response.data` shows that `Value` can be many things:

- a List: `"Value": []`
- a String: `"Value": "abc"`
- a Map: `"Value": { ... }`
- a Int: `"Value": 123`

**Note**

The first `Value` item in your `response.data` is a `List`. Which explains why the code is complaining about expecting a `Map` but getting a `List`.

**Solution**

`Value.fromJson(...)` needs to be able to handle lists, Strings, Ints, Maps etc. Not only Maps.

Comment: thanks so how can I edit my model from Value.fromJson?? I have been struggling with this.

Comment: I just help solving actual problems. I will not do your work, sorry.

Comment: Ok But on my value model, I made it receive different values like string and int